# How to access my computer's locale settings in the wpf app

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF(Windows) App for which I need to get the locale of the user or the system where application is running. I have changed the locale of my system to French as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acysF.png) and in the code I call "CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name", which is returning en-US always even though I change the locale of the system. Am I missing something here? Or is this not the right API to be used?

Comment: This section if for non-Unicode characters as written. Go to `Formats` and `Location` tabs and see what settings are setted.

Comment: I have set both of them to French as well. But no luck!

Comment: Did you try with CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture?

Comment: Yes. Even that is set to en-US.

Comment: This may be a cache problem. Use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData(); and retry

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem you need to use Windows Sensor API

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-7-Geolocation-API-25585fac